# Fetch lines based on regex match along with the filenames from a directory using apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

Given a regex and a hdfs directory, I need to list all the filenames with matching lines where the regex occurs. I am trying to do this using apache **spark**. Language **scala** preferable.

I need the return value somewhat in this format :

List< Map< filename:String,List< line:String> > >

by the following approach I can list all the file names.

```
val files = sc.wholeTextFiles(dirPath)
val regexpr = regex.r
var filter = files.filter{case(filename, content) => regexpr.findAllIn(content).length > 0 }
```

but I am not being able to fetch the exact lines where the regex occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SparkContext.wholeTextFiles`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles(java.lang.String,%20int)) returns an RDD where each file's contents is represented as a single string. If you want to break it back into lines, you'll have to do it yourslef, something like:

```
val files = sc.wholeTextFiles(dirPath)
val regexpr = regex.r
var filter = files
   .mapValues(content => content.split('\n')) // break each file into lines
   .mapValues(lines => lines.filter(l => regexpr.findFirstIn(l).isDefined))
```

Comment: Just the solution I wanted.. Thank you very much !!